How to update the ulimit values in the limits.conf file using Ansible?
I need to update the ulimit values in the limits.conf file for all the users.
Find the existing value (number, can be any value) and replace with the given value.
Examples
appadmin nproc 2000
mwadmin soft  nproc 1000
root   fsize    30000

Need to identify the values (2000, 1000 and 30000) set for nproc/fsize and replace with some fixed value like for nproc it will be 32000 and fsize will be 10000000.
Some parameter can have soft and some have hard. Also there is one or multiple space between the words (appadmin, nproc and 2000)
Trying to replace the existing ulimit value with fixed given value for all the users in limits.conf file.

So... What did you try so far?

@AlexanderPletnev, am new to ansible and tried few things with regular expression but its not even close to my requirements.


How to find numbers with matching string in a file and replace with another number using Ansible?

In short, you do not need to do that at all. Instead, it is recommended to use a specific module

... units of code that can control system resources or execute system commands. Ansible provides a module library that you can execute directly on Remote Hosts or through playbooks.

So you may have a look into the pam_limits module – Modify Linux PAM limits
In example a task
- name: Add or modify soft nproc limits for mwadmin domain
  pam_limits:
    domain: mwadmin
    limit_type: soft
    limit_item: nproc
    value: '1000'

will provide one required result.
Further Reading and Documentation

Things to know about programming using Ansible

Ansible is not a language:
If Ansible isn't a programming language, then what is it? Ansible is a tool written in Python, and it uses the declarative markup language YAML to describe the Desired State of devices and configuration. ... You declare aspects you want to be configured on a target device, such as that a file or directory exists, a package is installed, a service is running, and so on.


Ansible Best Practices: The Essentials

Think declaratively: Ansible is a Desired State Engine by design. If you’re trying to "write code" in your plays and roles, you’re setting yourself up for failure. Our YAML-based playbooks were never meant to be for programming.


What is the XY problem?



Thanks for the update. Its working. But i have to give the exact user name and type. otherwise its adding a new entry. We have 2000+ servers and each server might have different users and different type. Sometimes without soft and hard mentioned. So we need to find and change for all the users.
